# Django Grappelli Tabular Inline add new row TinyMCE textfield not editable

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce, django-tinymce, django-grappelli

I am using django Grappelli skin for my project.

I have a ModelAdmin with tabular inline function.

I use extra = 0 to prevent auto insert blank row, when the page is loaded. It works fine.

Now, when I click on the + sign to insert new row, the row is loaded, but the tinymce textfield is not editable.

Anyone know what is the reasons and how to solve this problem?

**After reading the document:**

http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#using-tinymce

**I notice:**

Using TinyMCE with Inlines is a bit more tricky because of the hidden empty-form. You need to write a custom template and use the inline-callbacks to

onInit: remove TinyMCE instances from the the empty-form.

onAfterAdded: initialize TinyMCE instance(s) from the form.

onBeforeRemoved: remove TinyMCE instance(s) from the form.

TinyMCE with Inlines is not supported by default.

**Any sample for this? I notice it is a TinyMCE functions that I need to change.**

Comment: Does anyone here know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. any update?

Answer (score 14):

It looks like some of the CSS classes and HTML structures used by Grappelli have changes since Almflm's solution was written. However, I was able to modify hir solution to work with Grappelli v2.4.7, and simplified the implementation in the process.

**Setup**

1. Override the relevant template by copying  `/PATH/TO/grappelli/templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html` to `/PATH/TO/YOURMOD/templates/admin/edit_inline/`
2. In your site's `settings.py`, ensure that YOURMOD is *above* grappelli in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Otherwise, Django will continue using the Grappelli version of the template.

**Code**

Now you just need to make two changes to your copy of `stacked.html`. Find the block of javascript that begins:

```
$("#{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group").grp_inline({
```

...and make the following changes inside that block:

1. Add an `onBeforeAdded` function like this (or modify the existing function if one exists, but I didn't have one):

   ```
       onBeforeAdded:function(form) {
           // New inlines start as a hidden template with class grp-empty-form.
           // This contains a textarea, which TinyMCE converts correctly, but
           // something about the transformation from template to visible 
           // form breaks TinyMCE, so we need to remove it from the template and 
           // then re-add it after the transformation. 
           // c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738173/
           if (tinyMCE != undefined) {
               django.jQuery('.grp-empty-form').find('textarea').each(function() { 
                   var tid = django.jQuery(this).attr("id");
                   tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl",false,tid); 
               });
           }
       },
   ```
2. Add the following to the `onAfterAdded` function (you should already have one, so be sure to modify the existing one rather than defining a new one!):

   ```
           if (tinyMCE != undefined) {
             // re-initialise tinyMCE instances
             deselector = tinyMCE.settings.editor_deselector;
             django.jQuery(form).find('textarea:not(.'+deselector+')').each(function(k,v) {
               var tid = django.jQuery(this).attr('id');
               tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, tid);
             });
           }
           // This line is optional. It just ensures that the new inline appears
           // un-collapsed, even if inlines are collapsed by default
           django.jQuery(form).removeClass("grp-closed").addClass("grp-open");
   ```

That's it!

**EDIT**
Added the deselector to the `onAfterLoad` - ensures you can still define a deselector class in a tinymce config file, and inlines will conform to this.

Comment: For tinymce 4.x, use mceAddEditor and mceRemoveEditor as command name instread of mceAddControl and mceRemoveControl respectively

Comment: This works but I'm not sure I'm a fan of this approach because you'll have to remember to update this template whenever you upgrade Grappelli.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have time to look into this more thoroughly, so I'm pretty sure there's a better solution, but this seems to work for me (tested with *django-grappelli 2.3.5* and *django-tinymce 1.5.1a2*.

I'm assuming that you are using *stacked* inlines.

You have to override a template from grappelli, `templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html`.
Inside the for-loop iterating over `inline_admin_formset|formsetsort:sortable_field_name`, right after the nested for-loop iterating over `inline_admin_form`, add this snippet:

```
{% if forloop.last %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (tinyMCE != undefined) {
      django.jQuery('textarea', '.empty-form').each(function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, django.jQuery(this).attr('id'));
      });
    }
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

it should disable tinyMCE controls for the textarea elements in the hidden 'empty-form', initialized by inline javascript rendered for the tinyMCE widget(s).

somewhere around the line 133 in the original grappelli template you'll see an invocation of `grp_inline()`. Add/modify the arguments:

```
$("#{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group").grp_inline({
  prefix: "{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}",
  onBeforeRemoved: function(f) {
    if (tinyMCE != undefined) {
      // make sure tinyMCE instances in empty-form are inactive
      django.jQuery('textarea', '.empty-form').each(function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, django.jQuery(this).attr('id'));
      });
    }
  },
  [...]
  onAfterAdded: function(form) {
    if (tinyMCE != undefined) {
      // re-initialise tinyMCE instances
      $('textarea', form).each(function(k,v) {
        var tid = $(this).attr('id');
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, tid);
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, tid);
      });
      // make sure tinyMCE instances in empty-form are inactive
      django.jQuery('textarea', '.empty-form').each(function() {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, django.jQuery(this).attr('id'));
      });
    }
    [...]
  }
  [...]
```

If you use sortables, you'd also want to disable tinyMCE controls on textareas of the inline being dragged. Look for the `sortable()` initialisation, and modify the 'start' callback:

```
start: function(evt, ui) {
  ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height() + 12);
  if (tinyMCE != undefined) {
    // make sure tinyMCE instances in empty-form are inactive
    $('textarea', ui.item).each(function(k,v) {
      var tid = $(this).attr('id');
      tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, tid);
    });
  }
},
[...]
```

This should give the rough idea how to work around this pesky problem...

Comment: This does not appear to work with the following versions: Django==1.4, django-tinymce==1.5.1b2, django-grappelli==2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that works for the following setup:

- Django==4.2
- django-grappelli==3.0.6
- django-nested-admin==4.0.2
- tinyMCE version 3

```js
// tinymce_setup.js
tinymce.init({
  // make sure you do not have `selector` defined here.
  mode: "none",
});

(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".djn-inline-form:not(.grp-empty-form) textarea").each(function () {
      // initialize MCE manually here rather than in `init` call.
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, this.id);
    });
  });
})(django.jQuery || window.jQuery);

(function ($) {
  $(document).on("formset:added", function (event, $form) {
    // initialize MCE manually when new formset is added
    $(".djn-inline-form:not(.grp-empty-form) textarea").each(function () {
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, this.id);
    });
  });
})(django.jQuery);
```

I am using `django-nested-admin` so make sure to adjust the target CSS class for your needs.

As it's stated in previous answer comments section you may need to adjust `execCommand` params if you are using other version of tinyMCE.

[Django Nested Admin Github's issue](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin/issues/47) that helped with finding the solution.

No need to override templates, just include this file as per [Django Grappelli documentation](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#using-tinymce)